# Not able to get HTTP Referrer in PHP

Tags: php, http-referer

We are developing an small application, in which our site will capture referrers others than our website. We have used below code to get referrer as:

```
if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])){  
  $referrer = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];  
}
```

The above code is working fine with almost all other websites, but we have found that "HTTP_REFERRER" variable is not defined for many websites like Facebook, LinkedIn, Yahoo etc. As result, we are not able to capture these websites.

Is there any other methods available to capture the referrer websites?

Comment: Referrer doesn't have to be sent. It's completely up to the browser whether it will send it or not, so if you've researched - you'd probably find that it's not something you can expect to exist.

Comment: No. The Referer header isn't guaranteed to be present, can be easily spoofed, and in particular won't be passed on by secure sites (e.g. those using https like Facebook or LinkedIn) to non-https sites. ["Clients SHOULD NOT include a Referer header field in a (non-secure) HTTP request if the referring page was transferred with a secure protocol."](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-15.1.3).

Comment: Thanks for reply! We want to just know that, if our site is https secured, then in that case, can we get referrers like facebook, yahoo etc? Or any other way to capture this.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the links used by these sites. They are not direct links, the sites intentionaly force the browsers not to send referrer header. You don't have any way around this.